# How to have flexible size of a text widget in Tcl/Tk

Tags: widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am dealing with a problem: I don't know how to have my text area adjustable with the window. When the window is enlarged, the text zone remain at its initial size and there is a lot of empty zone. 
My window's definition is following:

```
proc windowDef {} {

    destroy .frq

    # define the main text zone
    text .fr.txt -wrap word -yscroll {.fr.vscroll set} -highlightthickness 0
    scrollbar .fr.vscroll -orient vertical -command {.fr.txt yview}
    grid .fr.txt -column 0 -row 1 -sticky snwe
    grid .fr.vscroll -column 1 -row 1 -sticky snwe

    # define the canvas for interactive diagrams
    canvas .fr.canv -bg #f8f8f8 -yscrollcommand {.fr.vscroll set} -scrollregion "0 0 750 750"

    .fr.txt tag configure center -justify center
    .fr.txt configure -font "times 12" -state disabled

    .fr.vscroll configure -orient vertical -command {.fr.txt yview}
    grid .fr.txt -column 0 -row 1 -sticky snwe
    .fr.txt configure -state normal
    .fr.txt delete 1.0 end

    #questions frame
    frame .frq
    frame .frq.fr2 -background white
    grid .frq.fr2 -row 1

    label .frq.lbl -relief flat -font arial -text "Question 1 of 5"
    grid .frq.lbl -row 0
    text .frq.fr2.txt -relief flat -background white -font "times 13" -wrap word
    grid .frq.fr2.txt -columnspan 2 -row 1
    .frq.fr2.txt tag configure center -justify center
    grid rowconfigure .frq 1 -weight 1

    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb1 -command "choose A" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb1 -column 0 -row 2
    label .frq.fr2.lblA -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblA <ButtonRelease> "choose A; .frq.fr2.cb1 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblA -column 1 -row 2 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb2 -command "choose B" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb2 -column 0 -row 3
    label .frq.fr2.lblB -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblB <ButtonRelease> "choose B; .frq.fr2.cb2 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblB -column 1 -row 3 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb3 -command "choose C" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb3 -column 0 -row 4
    label .frq.fr2.lblC -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblC <ButtonRelease> "choose C; .frq.fr2.cb3 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblC -column 1 -row 4 -sticky w
    checkbutton .frq.fr2.cb4 -command "choose D" -cursor hand1
    grid .frq.fr2.cb4 -column 0 -row 5
    label .frq.fr2.lblD -background white -font "arial 12" -pady 3
    bind .frq.fr2.lblD <ButtonRelease> "choose D; .frq.fr2.cb4 toggle"
    grid .frq.fr2.lblD -column 1 -row 5 -sticky w

    frame .frq.bar
    grid .frq.bar -row 2
    button .frq.bar.next -text "Next question >>" -state disabled -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command "set ::goOn 1"
    pack .frq.bar.next -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.dp -text "Open drawing pad" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command notepad
    pack .frq.bar.dp -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.calc -text "Open calculator" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command calculator
    pack .frq.bar.calc -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none
    button .frq.bar.quit -text "Quit test" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command "set ::stop 1; set ::goOn 1"
    pack .frq.bar.quit -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none

    # title of section
    label .fr.titl
    .fr.titl configure -font "arial 20" -pady 10
    grid .fr.titl -column 0 -row 0 -sticky swe
    .fr.titl configure -background "White"

    #text styles
    .fr.txt tag configure Normal -font "times 12"
    .fr.txt tag configure subTitle -font "times 14"
    .fr.txt tag configure Titlec -font "times 16" -justify "center"
    .fr.txt tag configure subTitlec -font "times 14" -justify "center"
    .fr.txt tag configure subTitlecu -font "times 14"  -justify "center" -underline on
    .fr.txt tag configure Titlecu -font "times 16" -justify "center" -underline on
    .fr.txt tag configure Title -font "times 16"
    .fr.txt tag configure link -foreground blue -font "times 12"
    .fr.txt tag configure right -foreground "forest green"
    .fr.txt tag configure wrong -foreground red
    .fr.txt tag configure enhance -background "light goldenrod"
    .fr.txt tag configure rightenhance -background "light goldenrod" -foreground "forest green"
    .fr.txt tag bind link <Enter> ".fr.txt configure -cursor hand1"
    .fr.txt tag bind link <Leave> ".fr.txt configure -cursor arrow"
}
```

It is called by other procedures like the one following:

```
proc loadBackground {} {
    #variables
    set ::i 0
    set close 0
    set fd [open [pwd]/content/background r]
    set ::data [split [read $fd] \n]
    close $fd

    #window definition
    toplevel .fr
    wm title .fr "Background" 
    wm geometry .fr 750x750+0+105
    .fr configure -bg $::bgColour
    windowDef

    dispFile [lindex $::data $::i]

    #buttons definition 
    frame .fr.bar
    grid .fr.bar -row 2
    button .fr.bar.bk -text "<< Back" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command backFile
    pack .fr.bar.bk -padx 5 -pady 5 -side left -fill none
    button .fr.bar.cl -text "Close" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command { set close 1}
    pack .fr.bar.cl -padx 5 -pady 5 -side left -fill none
    button .fr.bar.nx -text "Next >>" -pady 5 -borderwidth 0 -command nextFile
    pack .fr.bar.nx -padx 5 -pady 5 -side right -fill none

    vwait close
    destroy .fr
    destroy .frq
}
```

The "pack" command of the geometry manager should be good, but I don't know how I can use it, yet there must be other solution I don't know.
I want to have the size of the text zone and the question frame flexible.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `grid` cell containing the `text` expand in both directions. To do that, both the row containing the cell and column containing the cell have to be given non-zero weights.

Thus, after:

```
    grid .fr.txt -column 0 -row 1 -sticky snwe
```

add these:

```
    grid rowconfigure .fr 1 -weight 1
    grid columnconfigure .fr 0 -weight 1
```

Remember, you're configuring the row and column of the grid in the master widget.

Also, if that master widget is a `frame` itself, make sure that it will also expand to fill the space available to it.

### If you were using `pack` instead of `grid`

There are equivalent thing with pack would have been:

```
    pack .fr.txt -expand 1 -fill both
```

While there are many differences between `pack` and `grid`, both require you to say when you want a widget to occupy space available to it. Also, when things get complicated, it can help a *lot* to make each widget (temporarily!) have a different coloured background, so you can see what it is actually doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!